# Call PowerUP via CLI

Tags: cleos, transactions

How can I purchse resources using the PowerUP model via CLI?

I see there are `net_frac` and `cpu_frac` params, which I don't know how to calculate. Is there any easy way to send a tx to say "I want to pay 0.0001 for CPU and 0.0001 for NET to run my next transaction?"

Answer (score 2):

I believe this was answered in Telegram but for others searching for the answer:

There is no way to calculate the net_frac/cpu_frac via cleos however Greymass created a library to [calculate net_frac/cpu_frac](https://github.com/greymass/eosio-resources). There is an example of how to use it [here](https://github.com/greymass/eosio-resources/blob/master/test/powerup.ts#L116-L123)

An example cleos command can be found [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/v1.9.2/docs/04_guides/08_configure-use-powerup-resource-model.md#executing-an-order)